# Can't drop columns from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I have a dataframe call df_col:[image]

```
print (df_col)
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10  c11  c12  c13  c14  c15  c16  \
0    5   4   4   5   4   4   4   4   4    5    4    4    3    3    4    3   
1    3   4   3   4   4   5   3   5   3    3    5    3    3    2    3    3   
2    4   4   5   5   4   4   4   4   4    4    5    4    4    1    3    2   
3    5   5   5   5   1   5   5   5   5    1    5    4    5    5    5    4   
4    5   5   5   5   5   5   5   4   5    2    5    4    4    5    2    2   
74   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   5   5    4    5    5    4    2    5    4   
75   5   3   4   5   5   5   4   5   4    5    5    4    4    4    4    3   
76   5   3   3   5   2   3   3   3   3    3    3    3    5    5    3    3   
77   4   5   4   2   2   4   4   4   5    4    5    5    3    3    4    2   
78   5   4   5   5   5   5   4   5   5    5    5    5    4    2    5    3   

    c17  c18  c19  c20  
0     4    4    3    3  
1     3    5    5    1  
2     3    3    4    3  
3     5    4    5    5  
4     5    5    5    3  
74    4    5    5    4  
75    3    4    5    4  
76    5    3    5    3  
77    4    5    5    2  
78    4    5    5    4
```

and a list call each_c:

`each criteria impact level =  [0.062, 0.031, 0.015, -0.016, 0.015, -0.031, 0.0, 0.015, 0.109, 0.0, 0.0, -0.031, -0.016, 0.219, 0.172, 0.031, 0.109, -0.016, 0.0, 0.062]`

I add each_c to df_col and then drop the columns where the min value in each_c belongs.

```
df_eachc = pd.DataFrame(each_c).T 
df_col.append(df_eachc, ignore_index=True)   
minui = min(each_c)  
for k in df_col:
   if minui < 0 :
      if k == minui:
        df_col.drop([k], axis=1, inplace=True, errors='raise')
        df_col.drop([minui], axis=1, inplace=True, errors='raise')
```

I need to drop -0.031 which are "c6" and "c12" for this, but it can't work.

Comment: What do you obtain? Are you able to post your input dataframe as copy-pastable datas instead of image?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare numpy array from list for not matched minimal values and filter in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
a = np.array(each_c)
df = df_col.loc[:, a != a.min()]
```

Or if convert to `Series` aslo pass index by column from `df_col`:

```
s = pd.Series(each_c, index=df_col.columns)
df = df_col.loc[:, s != s.min()]
```

---

```
print (df)
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c7  c8  c9  c10  c11  c13  c14  c15  c16  c17  c18  \
0    5   4   4   5   4   4   4   4    5    4    3    3    4    3    4    4   
1    3   4   3   4   4   3   5   3    3    5    3    2    3    3    3    5   
2    4   4   5   5   4   4   4   4    4    5    4    1    3    2    3    3   
3    5   5   5   5   1   5   5   5    1    5    5    5    5    4    5    4   
4    5   5   5   5   5   5   4   5    2    5    4    5    2    2    5    5   
74   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   5    4    5    4    2    5    4    4    5   
75   5   3   4   5   5   4   5   4    5    5    4    4    4    3    3    4   
76   5   3   3   5   2   3   3   3    3    3    5    5    3    3    5    3   
77   4   5   4   2   2   4   4   5    4    5    3    3    4    2    4    5   
78   5   4   5   5   5   4   5   5    5    5    4    2    5    3    4    5   

    c19  c20  
0     3    3  
1     5    1  
2     4    3  
3     5    5  
4     5    3  
74    5    4  
75    5    4  
76    5    3  
77    5    2  
78    5    4
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, 
can I know what's the problem in my original code?

Comment: @LeoChen - for me not working `df_eachc = pd.DataFrame(each_c).T 
df_col.append(df_eachc, ignore_index=True)` It create incorrect new column, for you working?